# What Star Trek episodes/films portray Federation legal proceedings?

Tags: star-trek, laws, federation, star-trek-movies

Courtrooms provide the context for great drama because of the high stakes.
Star Trek is no exception at taking advantage.

## What Star Trek episodes/films portray Federation legal proceedings?

Related: [What major non-Federation Star Trek cultures' legal proceedings are portrayed in episodes or films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106728/what-star-trek-episodes-films-portray-legal-proceedings-of-major-alien-species)

Related: [In what episodes did the legal systems of "one-off" aliens provide a key plot-element?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106750/in-what-episodes-did-the-legal-systems-of-one-off-aliens-provide-a-key-plot-el)

Comment: Shameless plugging of your own question; I like it!

Comment: @TheDoc, it's a cluster of questions to keep the answer sizes under control.   There may be a third if these are well-received.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Lawyer

Comment: It's been awhile since you asked this, but do you want to include instances where the outcome of a legal decision is seen but not the actual reaching of the decision? Ex. Paris is put into the brig for violating the Prime Directive, but we don't actually see Janeway pass the judgement. Or Doctor Bashir is sentenced to prison for Julian's genetic manipulation, but we don't see the JAG office bring the case before a judge.

Comment: @Xantec:   *portray legal proceedings* means we need to see some form of legal proceed.   But you can add as a borderline case, if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer.   Add at will:

- *TOS*: 'The Menagerie' - Spock is the subject of a court-martial
- *TOS*: 'Court Martial' - Kirk is put on trial for the manslaughter of Ben Finney
- *TOS*: 'Amok Time' - Spock, *in extremis* from the 7-year Vulcan biological imperative, is taken back to Vulcan and pressed into legal one-sided divorce proceedings involving combat initiated by his wife, T'Pring; shocking surprise at T'Pring's selection of champion follows.
- *TNG*: 'Measure of a Man' - Data is involved in a legal case determining his legal rights under Federation law
- *TNG*: 'The Drumhead' - several courts-martial in an attempt to uncover a conspiracy
- *DS9*: 'Rules of Engagement' - Worf is charged with war crimes for destruction of an unarmed civilian vessel
- *VOY*: 'Author, Author' - the Doctor's rights following the unauthorised publishing of his holonovel are discussed with a legal case involved

Comment: Also, TNG: The Drumhead- You beat me to "Measure of a Man", one of my favorite eps

Comment: Not sure if the beginning of 'Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home' should be added. It is perhaps more of a diplomatic thing than a trial.

Comment: It seems as if the *end* of ST IV should be counted; a plea is entered, sentence is passed.

Comment: *Amok Time* isn't really a Federation legal proceeding is it? While Vulcan is a Federation member, their marriage rituals would be an internal matter.

Answer (score 0):

VOY: 'Ex Post Facto' - Tom Paris is convicted of murder and has to witness the event from the victim's perspective every 14 hours.

Comment: That wasn't a Federation legal case though.