# What major non-Federation Star Trek cultures' legal proceedings are portrayed in episodes or films?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, laws

Courtrooms provide the context for great drama because of the high stakes.
Star Trek is no exception at taking advantage.

## What major Star Trek cultures' legal proceedings are portrayed in episodes or films?

Examples: Klingons, Cardassians, Bajorans, Ferengi, Romulans, pre-Federation humans

Related: [What major non-Federation Star Trek cultures' legal proceedings are portrayed in episodes or films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106728/what-star-trek-episodes-films-portray-legal-proceedings-of-major-alien-species)

Related: [In what episodes did the legal systems of "one-off" aliens provide a key plot-element?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106750/in-what-episodes-did-the-legal-systems-of-one-off-aliens-provide-a-key-plot-el)

Comment: Do episodes showing penal processes also count?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer.   Add at will:

**World War III-style court**

- *TNG*: 'Encounter at Farpoint' - Q charges Humanity of being a grievously savage race

**Klingon legal system**

- *ENT*: 'Judgement' - Captain Archer is tried in a Klingon tribunal for attacking a Klingon ship and inciting a rebellion.
- *TOS*: *The Undiscovered Country* - Kirk and McCoy are tried for assassination of Chancellor Gorkon
- *DS9*: 'The House of Quark' - Grilka and Quark must establish Quark as the rightful leader of Grilka's house before The Klingon High Council.
- *TNG*: 'Sins of the Father' - Worf must defend his family's honor before the high council, while Picard acts as his Cha'DIch.
- *TNG*: 'Reunion' - The dying emperor K'mpec chooses Picard to arbitrate the Rite of Succession, in which either Duras or Gowron will become the next emperor.

**Cardassian legal system**

- *DS9*: 'Tribunal' - O'Brien is charged with selling weapons to the Maquis.

**Bajoran legal system**

- *DS9*: 'Dax' - Jadzia Dax is the subject of an extradition hearing over an accusation of murder against Dax's former host, Curzon.

**Ferengi legal system**

- *DS9*: 'Body Parts' - Quark has his Ferengi Business License summarily revoked by the Ferengi Commerce Authority, in the person of Brunt, for breaking a contract.

Comment: @beichst the 'Rubicon star system' incident has already been mentioned as 'Edo legal system'.

Comment: Oh my, why did the Edo give in!?

Comment: Note:  Episodes involving one-off legal systems belong [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106751/3823)

Comment: In the Voyager episode "Distant Origin", we saw the Dinosaur species's court system as well

Comment: @NateWatson:   Moving to other question.

Comment: I'm not sure who it was, but I remember an episode in TNG where they visit a planet populated by humans. Wesly falls into a plant box or something and breaks it. They leave planet and the leader of the colony talks to Riker and says that the crime is punishable by death. Not sure if it counts though.

Comment: @Zymus, that's the Edo.  See the other linked question.

Comment: TOS _Balance of Terror_ gives a little information about the Romulan legal system - the 'Right of Statement'.

Comment: @LAK You're mixing up episodes. "Balance of Terror" was their sci-fi take on WWII Allied destroyer vs German U-boat. "Right of statement" was from "The Enterprise Incident" (Enterprise surrounded by Romulans using Klingon warships).

Comment: TNG "The Outcast" - Soren of the J'naii before a tribunal about her indiscretions with Riker. Voyager "Ex Post Facto" Tom Paris is framed for a murder. TNG "A Matter of Perspective" - Riker is suspected of murder.

Comment: @Anthony X, You're right ,of course.  I don't know how I could have made that mistake; they're two of my favorite episodes, and I'm very familiar with them.  Must have had a lot on my mind when I made the comment.